# How to use tensorboard plots for list/arrays?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorboardx

I have a list of values(loss values).

loss = [0.9,0.7,0.6,0.4]

I did not use tensorboard callback while training. Now I want to plot those values in tensorboard.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need the logs for plotting in TensorBoard. If you want to plot these values, just use `matplotlib`.